# Drawn lines with touch location shrinking and fading into background Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am experiencing a weird bug on Swift 3.0 whereby I am successfully drawing into a UIImageView that is located inside a UIView, however as I draw the previously drawn line begins to fade and shrink into the top of UIImageView and becomes extremely blurry as shown in the attached images.
[Beginning of Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOKPU.png), [Image becoming blurry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSWaP.png).

I would appreciate any help/guidance that could be provided.

```
class DrawView: UIView {
    var drawArea: UIImageView!
    var clearDrawArea: UIButton!
    var lastTouch = CGPoint.zero

    init(){
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.135, y:UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.05, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.8, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.9))
        drawArea = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: self.bounds.width*0.9, height: self.bounds.height*0.86))
        drawArea.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let buttonWidth = self.bounds.width*0.2
        let buttonHeight = self.bounds.height*0.1
        clearDrawArea = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (self.bounds.width*0.61)-(buttonWidth/2), y: self.bounds.height*0.94, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight))
        clearDrawArea.setTitle("Clear Draw Area", for: .normal)
        clearDrawArea.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 49/255, green: 200/255, blue: 134/255, alpha: 255)
        clearDrawArea.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resetImage), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.addSubview(clearDrawArea)
        self.addSubview(drawArea)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let firstTouch = touches.first{

            lastTouch = firstTouch.location(in: drawArea)
        }

    }
    func drawLines(_ from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawArea.frame.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: from.x, y: from.y))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: to.x, y: to.y))

        context?.setLineCap(.round)
        context?.setLineWidth(3)
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)

        context?.strokePath()

        drawArea.image?.draw(in: drawArea.bounds)
        drawArea.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


        if let firstTouch = touches.first{
            let touchLocation = firstTouch.location(in: drawArea)
            drawLines(lastTouch, to: touchLocation)

            lastTouch = touchLocation
        }
    }

    func resetImage(){

        drawArea.image = nil            
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Thank you for help. I am simply trying to allow the user just to draw on the screen where ever they touch and just for it to be left behind. when i implement the code in a view controller class using the bounds of the whole screen it works as intended but when i try to restrict to just a UIView it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Changed your code a bit try the following..

```
class DrawView: UIView {
var drawArea: UIImageView!
var clearDrawArea: UIButton!
var lastTouch = CGPoint.zero
let pathAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"animation")
let tempPathLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
var lineLayer:CAShapeLayer=CAShapeLayer()
init(){
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.135, y:UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.05, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.8, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.9))
    drawArea = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: self.bounds.width*0.9, height: self.bounds.height*0.86))
    drawArea.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let buttonWidth = self.bounds.width*0.2
    let buttonHeight = self.bounds.height*0.1
    clearDrawArea = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (self.bounds.width*0.61)-(buttonWidth/2), y: self.bounds.height*0.94, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight))
    clearDrawArea.setTitle("Clear Draw Area", for: .normal)
    clearDrawArea.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 49/255, green: 200/255, blue: 134/255, alpha: 255)
    clearDrawArea.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resetImage), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.addSubview(clearDrawArea)
    self.addSubview(drawArea)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let firstTouch = touches.first{

        lastTouch = firstTouch.location(in: drawArea)
    }

}
func drawLines(_ from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint){
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawArea.frame.size)

    //let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let tempPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    var lineLayer:CAShapeLayer=CAShapeLayer()
    tempPath.move(to: from)
    tempPath.addLine(to: to)
    let strokeColor = UIColor.red
    UIColor.blue.setFill()
    strokeColor.setStroke()

    let tempPathLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    tempPathLayer.frame = self.bounds
    tempPathLayer.position=self.layer.position
    tempPathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    tempPathLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    tempPathLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    tempPathLayer.path = tempPath.cgPath
    lineLayer=tempPathLayer
    pathAnimation.beginTime=CACurrentMediaTime()
    pathAnimation.duration = 2
    pathAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: 0.0)
    pathAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value:1.0)

    lineLayer.add(pathAnimation, forKey: "animation")
    self.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)

    drawArea.image?.draw(in: drawArea.bounds)
    drawArea.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    if let firstTouch = touches.first{
        let touchLocation = firstTouch.location(in: drawArea)
        drawLines(lastTouch, to: touchLocation)

        lastTouch = touchLocation
    }
}

func resetImage(){

    drawArea.image = nil            
}
```

}

Comment: I attempted to use the code you added with amendments however the drawn lines do not remain and leave a short trail behind the users touch

Comment: Can you check once again? Cause the same code provides the result for me.

Comment: I checked again and it still does as I mentioned. I tested on an iPad as well to make sure. Is strange it works on yours. To isolate the problem further I tested my code on a completely blank view controller with the imageview the same size as the screen and it worked perfectly. problems only occur when implement it inside an imageview inside a UIView class. I also reduced the size of the imageview on that viewcontroller and it still works as intended.

Comment: Maybe if I move the functionality into the UIView's parentcontroller might provide some luck?

Comment: Are you saying the code is working on a blank view controller as expected?

Comment: yes my code works when i implement it the drawing functionality inside a view controller class. but if i try to move the functionality into a uiview class it doesnt work

Comment: Omg thats it haha. I had to move all of the functionality out of the uiview itself and into the viewcontroller. I dont understand why though which is kinda frustrating

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. Even though your solution did not work on mine, it helped to narrow down where the issue was. :)

Comment: Wait it isnt to do with the UIView class. the drawing functionality does not work when i move the imageview away from the top left hand corner of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I have finally got it to work properly. I took advantage of your idea to use bezier paths instead and modified it to limit the drawing scope to the UIView.

```
class DrawView: UIView {
var drawArea: UIImageView!
var clearDrawArea: UIButton!
var lastTouch = CGPoint.zero
var context: CGContext!
var path: UIBezierPath!
init(){
    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    path = UIBezierPath()
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.135, y:UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.05, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.8, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.9))
    drawArea = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: self.bounds.width*0.9, height: self.bounds.height*0.86))
    drawArea.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let buttonWidth = self.bounds.width*0.2
    let buttonHeight = self.bounds.height*0.1
    clearDrawArea = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (self.bounds.width*0.61)-(buttonWidth/2), y: self.bounds.height*0.94, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight))
    clearDrawArea.setTitle("Clear Draw Area", for: .normal)
    clearDrawArea.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 49/255, green: 200/255, blue: 134/255, alpha: 255)
    clearDrawArea.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resetImage), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.addSubview(clearDrawArea)
    self.addSubview(drawArea)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let firstTouch = touches.first{

        lastTouch = firstTouch.location(in: drawArea)
    }

}
func drawLines(_ from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint){
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawArea.frame.size)

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: from.x, y: from.y))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: to.x, y: to.y))

    UIColor.black.setStroke()
    path.lineWidth = 3
    path.stroke()

    context?.saveGState()
    context?.addPath(path.cgPath)
    context?.closePath()
    context?.restoreGState()

    drawArea.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    if let firstTouch = touches.first {
        let touchLocation = firstTouch.location(in: drawArea)
        drawLines(lastTouch, to: touchLocation)

        lastTouch = touchLocation
    }
}

func resetImage(){
    path.removeAllPoints()
    drawArea.image = nil            
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. I fixed it by altering the constraints so that the view was pinned to the view controller. I originally had an aspect ratio, and it was causing this problem in the 6/7 size, but not the 5/SE size or the PLUS sizes. this may be why upon testing the code that another answer submitted, it worked for them but not for you. if the uiView and the drawingarea are not aligned and sizing correctly, it will distort your drawing/cause 'striations' big lines that seem to come from no where/only draw on certain areas/you will touch in one place and it will draw somewhere else.

I recommend testing all screen sizes to ensure your functionality works on all of them and looks correct with the constraint settings you have.